# Aws Policy Rejection

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Currently spinning wheels while using terraform with the aws provider. The policy below seems valid, but it keeps being rejected. I can't figure out why this is invalid Json for policy:

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "aws_dms_secret_sql_server_policy" {
name = "${var.application}-${replace(var.service, "-", "")}-${replace(data.aws_region.current.name, "-", "")}-${terraform.workspace}-dms_secret_sql_server_policy"
policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
            "Resource": "${module.rds_staging.secrets_manager_secret_arn}"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                    "kms:Decrypt",
                    "kms:DescribeKey"
                    ],
            "Resource": "${module.rds_staging.secrets_manager_kms_key_arn}" 
        }
    ]
}
EOF
tags = local.common_tags
}
```

Here is the terraform error:

```
Error: "policy" contains an invalid JSON policy

  with aws_iam_policy.aws_dms_secret_sql_server_policy,
  on dms-bronze-iam.tf line 88, in resource "aws_iam_policy" "aws_dms_secret_sql_server_policy":
  88:     policy = <<EOF
  89:     {
  90:         "Version": "2012-10-17",
  91:         "Statement": [
  92:             {
  93:                 "Effect": "Allow",
  94:                 "Action": "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
  95:                 "Resource": "${module.rds_staging.secrets_manager_secret_arn}"
  96:             },
  97:             {
  98:                 "Effect": "Allow",
  99:                 "Action": [
 100:                         "kms:Decrypt",
 101:                         "kms:DescribeKey"
 102:                         ],
 103:                 "Resource": "${module.rds_staging.secrets_manager_kms_key_arn}"
 104:             }
 105:         ]
 106:     }
 107:     EOF
```

Comment: Try using `jsonencode(...)` instead of heredoc syntax.

Comment: I'm not seeing the error, but honestly if you have a JSON format error, why not paste it into a JSON validator online instead of asking people to manually spot it for you here?

Comment: @MarkB - I did that before I posted and validator returned -Valid JSON

Comment: @RossBush OK, that would have been pertinent info to include in the question. I really don't see the JSON error in your code, it looks just like some Terraform code I have. As mentioned by others, you could use `jsonencode()`, or you could use the `aws_iam_policy_document` data source to build your policy, either of which would be guaranteed to generate valid JSON. https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_policy_document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON must be invalid when evaluated. The terraform documentation states:

> Don't use "heredoc" strings to generate JSON or YAML. Instead, use the jsonencode function or the yamlencode function so that Terraform can be responsible for guaranteeing valid JSON or YAML syntax.

so, using the [jsonencode function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/jsonencode):

```
jsonencode({
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
            "Resource": "${module.rds_staging.secrets_manager_secret_arn}"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                    "kms:Decrypt",
                    "kms:DescribeKey"
                    ],
            "Resource": "${module.rds_staging.secrets_manager_kms_key_arn}" 
        }
    ]
})
```

Comment: That would only be an issue if indentation was part of JSON syntax, but it is not. I have plenty of IAM policies in Terraform using the exact heredoc syntax as in the question, and it works fine.

Comment: @MarkB so what's the solution to op's problem then?

Comment: If I knew that I would post it as an answer. I'm just saying your Heredoc comment is incorrect. Using `<<EOF` is fine for a JSON IAM policy.

Comment: @MarkB fair enough

Comment: @Paolo - I don't know why. For some reason <<-EOF worked. I wil attempt to migrate to jsonencode as described above.

Comment: @MarkB looks like `-EOF` worked after all!